# How do I uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, windows, partitioning, uninstall

How do I format drive and unistall Ubuntu 11.10?  I wanted a dual boot and was given an option to overwrite Windows XP partition and said yes.  Format options don't work.  I tried a few dos prompts and probably not using correct fdisk.  Format options state drive is busy closed all windows.  Tried to boot windows XP and disk says its corrupt.

Comment: You won't be able to boot Windows XP now because you overwrote its partition when you installed Ubuntu; all of that data is now gone. If you want to run Windows XP, you'll need the Windows XP installation CD or a recovery disc. It will have to reformat your drive to its own filesystem format and do a complete reinstall.

Comment: Please clarify your question, it's really difficult to understand in its current form. "I wanted a dual boot and ... overwritten Windows XP partion" - how do you expect dual boot to work if you removed Windows XP? What dos prompts are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling Ubuntu is a complex process. But you can simply remove it from your system without any harm in following case. Try this, but be cautious.

Read my blog entry at [WordPress](http://techareena.wordpress.com/2010/07/31/how-to-remove-ubuntu-from-windows/) for advanced options. Also given below, but still you can refer the other.

Login to your Windows XP. Windows's boot loader is named as Master Boot Record or MBR. While installing Ubuntu after Windows, this MBR will be replaced by Linux Grub. When you remove Ubuntu, Windows has no boot loaders and boot will failure. So what you need to do is to restore MBR. Well, it is not so complicated process with EasyBCD software. You can download it from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml). Download and install this software into your machine.

Now open your device manager. From there you need to open disk management window. Wait for few seconds since it requires some time to display disk information. Now you can see your disk's partitions. NTFS refers to Windows and Ext refers to Linux. Simply select on Linux partition and right click on it. Now choose delete partition. Be sure you are selecting and deleting linux partition only. Now your Ubuntu is away from your system. Things are not so ready yet. You need to change this volume into Windows' drive to use it in Windows. Again right click on it and select New simple volume. Follow on screen dialogues and create the new partition.

Now open EasyBCD software. You can see an option BootLoader and choose Install Windows XP boot loader to MBR under MBR options. You are done with. Now close everything and reboot your system.

You can refer EasyBCD's working in this [site](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Recovering+the+Vista+Bootloader+with+EasyBCD)